# Magento 2.2.0 : TypeError: element.getRecordCount is not a function in dynamic rows in admin form

Tags: magento2.2, dynamic-rows

I have created custom modules with Magento 2.1.6 and there is `dynamic rows` added in custom module form. Where admin can add dynamic data with the help of magento dynamic rows. And It is working fine with that magento version.
But when I have integrated that same module in Magento 2.2.0, it is not working and below error occurred.

`TypeError: element.getRecordCount is not a function`

How can I resolve this issue ?